# Fill in website search bar using Excel VBA

Tags: html, forms, vba, excel

I'm trying to make an Excel macro that inserts data into a web search form and then copies the results into a table. The web search form is not actually a "form", but a blank table  so I can't just change the input value of the form because there is none:

```
<td valign="top">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <th class="navLabelText" align="left">Order:</th>
            <td>
                <input class="navEditField" id="opt_ordernumber_int" name="ordernumber" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
```

The HTML just continues with more of the same types of forms (I'm guessing coded in Java since the site is a .jsp). Is there any way that I can pass values into the blank table?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub featurecode()

Dim ie As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim links As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim link As HTMLAnchorElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
Dim todaysURL As String

Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True 'false
ie.navigate "https://website.com"
Application.StatusBar = "Loading Feature Codes"

Do Until ie.readyState = IE_READYSTATE.complete: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = ie.document


' Find the input tag of the order form and submit button:
Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "ordernumber" Then

        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "655032"

    Else
        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And objCollection(i).Name = "Submit" Then

            ' "Search" button is found
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
            objElement.Click

        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

The part that I'm having trouble with is this:

```
If objCollection(i).Name = "ordernumber" Then

    ' Set text for search
    objCollection(i).Value = "655032"
```

Usually you can change the HTML value of the form, but in this case there is no HTML value in the input tag, so I'm at a loss. My goal here is to simply insert an order number into the form and hit the submit button. Unfortunately I can't show you the website as it's an internal corporate site, but here's a screenshot of the relevant info: [screenshot](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9850/79951377.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried anything so far? (As a new user, you may want to review the [ask] FAQ for help in getting the answers you're looking for.)

Comment: Would it be possible for us to see the link to that website?

Comment: What have you got so far?  Have you ever tried something like this before?  It's useful to give some idea of your level of knowledge so we can pitch any suggestions at the right level.

Comment: @user - if there's no "value" attribute in the <input> element in the source HTML that's OK: when you set the value via your code it should still be sent when you submit the form. Note - since your input element has an "id" attribute, you can just use `doc.getElementById("opt_ordernumber_int").value = "655032"`: no need to loop to find the input.

Answer (score -1):

I've found with some elements in VBA, including INPUT, you have to focus on the element first:

```
    objCollection(i).Focus
    objCollection(i).Value = "655032"
```